# Trying to figure out time complexites

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I am trying to figure out time complexities for the following:

First:

```
 j = 1
 while j < n:
    j += log(j + 5)
```

Would this be **log n**?

Secondly, a recurrence relation:

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) + n
```

I know you can't apply Master Theorem here but I am not sure how to find the complexity otherwise. A solution would be nice, but references to how to help me understand this would be good I guess.

Next, another recurrence relation:

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + log(n)
```

I am fairly certain that Master Theorem **can** be applied here. Leaving us with:

```
 a = 1, b = 2, f(n) = log(n)
```

This means we would compare

```
 n^(log_2(1)) to log(n) ==> n^0 to log(n)
```

Making it Theta(log(n))

Finally

```
 j=1
 while(j<n):
    k=j
    while k<n:
       k += sqrt(k)
    j += 0.25*j
```

I can tell that the outer loop will run 4 times.  I am unclear as to the inner loop, however. Would it be **log^2 n** **log log n** or am I completely off in my thinking.

I am just studying for a test and am finding the materials at my disposal to be woefully inadequate.

Comment: The first is O=log(n) - assuming log is O(1)

Comment: `while i < n:
    j += log(j + 5)` never occurs or is an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at the result for `log^2 n log log n`?

Comment: I literally have no idea now that I look back on it, I believe I meant log^2 n. I am all sorts of confused when it comes to the square root.  I looks like it's just going to regress to taking square roots of 2+sqrt(2).

Answer (score 0):

The First is `O(n)` as we know each time at least `1` added to the previous result.

If you exapand the recurrent equation, the second is:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/4) + T(n/8) + n + n/2 < 3T(n/4) + 3n/2
```

We can say from master theorem that `T(n) = \Theta(n)`.

The third is true and it is `\Theta(log(n))`.
Outer loop in the forth loop is `T(n+1) = 5T(n)/4`. It means outer loop is run `log_{1.25}n`. In the worst case, we can say the inner loop runs in `O(n)`. Hence, it would be `O(nlog(n))`. If you want tighter complexity analysis, you should scrutinize more,.

Comment: @basil The same!

Comment: For the second one, how were you able to get that? How are you finding those numbers?

Comment: fixed 4th problem

Comment: @meowgoesthedog why?

Comment: Apologies that was a mistake; however it's definitely sub-linear, probably `O(n / log n)`.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes. I'm on your side. But, we should scrutinize more on the analysis.

Comment: @OmG what do you mean by "scrutinize more"? I don't see how you could use MT for the second... what do you mean by expanding the relation and how does it allow you to use MT? I apologize if these are simple questions, my course is absolute ass and doesn't stop to explain what are apparently basic concepts at all.